# Accessing a URL stored in a variable from a controller

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-5

I am in a confusing situation

In my Laravel controller, I have a variable

```
public function storeName($key)
$store = new Store();
$storeName = $store->connectAPI($key);
```

This $storeName variable will actually give me a URL, which if accessed, will give me a JSON response.

If I die and dump $storeName variable it will print

```
http://store123.com?key=2093983892
```

But, what I actually want is to access this $storeName variable, by passing a GET request in my controller, so I can get a JSON response from this API call.

How can I access this URL in my controller?

Comment: try json_decode(file_get_contents($url))

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used json_decode inside a curl_init function to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

From [Guzzle docs](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/)

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$res = $client->request('GET', 'https://api.github.com/user', []);
if($res->getStatusCode())
{
// "200"

$json = $res->getBody();
}
```

Comment: Before you suggest using Guzzle, at least explain what it is and why it should be used.